# How to count the number of times each function is inlined when compiling with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, inline, compiler-optimization

I'm compiling for a very small embedded platform where every kilobyte matters.  Sometimes the compilation fails because a certain function is inlined excessively causing code bloat.

Is there a way to get a mapping between function name and the number of times it was inlined so that I can tell gcc explicitly not to inline a function where the size vs speed trade-off is not worth it?  I otherwise want to optimise for speed, so just compiling with -Os is not an option.

Comment: When viewing the disassembly, you might be able to search for the function name. If it isn't there, but it is there in the C source, then it was inlined. Or alternatively you can check in the map file if the function was even allocated at a memory position. And in case you've found a function which you don't want inlined, you could move it to a separate translation unit (.c file), which usually blocks inlining.

Comment: I always thought that `-O2` only inlines functions when there is no or only a minimal size trade off. Are you using `-O3`?

Comment: @mch I made a quick check with Godbolt.org, and GCC seems to inline functions starting with `-O1`. GCC will not inline functions when using `-O0`, but the latter option would generate too big code size in my opinion (plus, it would be slower code).

Comment: Off the wall idea: macro the function name to something like `x # __LINE__` and then count the linking failures.

Comment: I don't use GCC on a daily basis, but your question made me wonder whether the compiler doesn't have support for logging, and apparently it [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584716/getting-an-optimization-report-from-gcc) (or at least did) - IHTH.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Promising lead, will look into that, thanks!

Comment: @mch I'm using -Ofast, which I believe is based on -O3

Comment: @DanSandberg yes, that's the problem. You should not use -Ofast or -O3 for embedded targets without looking at the code size. It inlines too much.