# How do I enable and get the loop vectorization report from GCC run under Code Blocks?

Tags: gcc, optimization, vectorization, codeblocks, compiler-flags

MY QUESTION IS:  ***Re. loop vectorizer report generated by GCC. i get no report (optrpt.txt) also although i want a printed report what is stderr?. **What compiler flags should i be using to generate the report and have it printed to optrpt.txt?**?***

See similar question:
[Getting an optimization report from GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584716/getting-an-optimization-report-from-gcc)
But this has not solved my problem, it is mainly the same info that is in the following.

See for instructions and examples:
https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html

An example output of the report from the above website follows:

For the example using the flag:
-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2:

produces for the example:

> vect-1.c:82: note: not vectorized, possible dependence between
> data-refs a[i_124] and a[i_83] vect-1.c:72: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
> vect-1.c:64: note: LOOP VECTORIZED. vect-1.c:56: note: LOOP
> VECTORIZED. vect-1.c:49: note: LOOP VECTORIZED. vect-1.c:41: note: not
> vectorized: unsupported use in stmt. vect-1.c:31: note: not
> vectorized: unsupported use in stmt. vect-1.c:13: note: vectorized 4
> loops in function.

In my case I am using Win 11 on an AMD Ryzen with code in C. and Code Blocks with the recent GCC version 20.03 running at -O3.
I am using the following flags:

-fopenmp

-march=native

-msse2

-ftree-vectorize

-ffast-math

-fopt-info-vec-all=optrpt.txt

i followed instructions from the above website to setup the flags.

Answer (score -1):

i added -C to the end of my flags and that solved my problem.  i do not know why.  i was trying to get an assembly code listing.